# About generalized hough transform code

Tags: c++, image-processing, hough-transform

I was looking for an implementation of Generalized Hough Transform,and then I found [this website](http://www.itriacasa.it/generalized-hough-transform/GHT.html),which showed me a complete implementation of GHT .

I can totally understand how the algorithm processes except this:

```
Vec2i referenceP = Vec2i(id_max[0]*rangeXY+(rangeXY+1)/2, id_max[1]*rangeXY+(rangeXY+1)/2);
```

which calculates the reference point of the object based on the maximum value of the hough space,then mutiplied by `rangXY` to get back to the corresponding position of origin image.(`rangeXY` is the dimensions in pixels of the squares in which the image is divided. )

I edited the code to

```
Vec2i referenceP = Vec2i(id_max[0]*rangeXY, id_max[1]*rangeXY);
```

and I got another reference point then [show all edgePoints in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4s0h.png),which apparently not fit the shape.

I just cannot figure out what the factor`(rangeXY+1)/2`means.

Is there anyone who has implemented this code or familiared with the rationale of GHT can tell me what the factor `rangeXY`means? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am familiar with the classic Hough Transform, though not with the generalised one. However, I believe you give enough information in your question for me to answer it without being familiar with the algorithm in question.

`(rangeXY+1)/2` is simply integer division by 2 with rounding. For instance `(4+1)/2` gives 2 while `(5+1)/2` gives 3 (2.5 rounds up). Now, since `rangeXY` is the side of a square block of pixels and `id_max` is the position (index) of such a block, then `id_max[dim]*rangeXY+(rangeXY+1)/2` gives the position of the central pixel in that block.

On the other hand, when you simplified the expression to `id_max[dim]*rangeXY`, you were getting the position of the top-left rather than the central pixel.

Comment: `rangeXY/2` indeed looks like a better option, as the center of a 5x5 pixel block is at position (2, 2) not (3, 3).